# regex to create file name from image alt tag

Tags: regex

Given this as input:

```
<IMG alt="Just do it." src="http://25.media.moo.com/moo_kjasdf0nd_500.jpg">
```

How can I get as the output:

```
Just-do-it.jpg
```

Comment: It's an application that allows regex's.... I can pull multiple variables by putting parenthesis around them, then concatenate them like $1$2 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using Python's re:

```
>>> import re
>>> input = '''<IMG alt="Just do it." src="http://25.media.moo.com/moo_kjasdf0nd_500.jpg">'''
>>> pattern =  '''.*alt="([^"]*).*src=".*([.][^.]+)"'''
>>> re.match(pattern,input).groups() 
('Just do it.', '.jpg')
>>>
```

I'll leave assembling the parts as an exercise :)

Comment: Thanks, though I would like to do a regex replace on the spaces to a -

Comment: That's easier done with a string operation than within the regex, at least in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think regex is not necessary for this.

Just parse the string in the right way.

1. First, strip off the '<', '>' and the tag name.
2. Then split the remaining by whitespace.
3. Split each part by '=' to get the attribute names and values.
4. Then find out the ones with attribute names 'alt' and 'src', then combine their values to get the file name.